# gradient descent using tensors calculating wrong values

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, gradient-descent

I am implementing simple gradient descent algorithm using tensors. It learns two parameters **m** and **c**.
 The normal python code for it is :

```
for i in range(epochs): 
    Y_pred = m*X + c  # The current predicted value of Y
    D_m = (-2/n) * sum(X * (Y - Y_pred))  # Derivative wrt m
    D_c = (-2/n) * sum(Y - Y_pred)  # Derivative wrt c
    m = m - L * D_m  # Update m
    c = c - L * D_c  # Update c
    print (m, c)
```

output for python :

```
0.7424335285442664 0.014629895049575754
1.1126970531591416 0.021962519495058154
1.2973530613155333 0.025655870599552183
1.3894434413955663 0.027534253868790198
1.4353697670010162 0.028507481513901086
```

Tensorflow equivalent code :

```
#Graph of gradient descent
y_pred = m*x + c
d_m = (-2/n) * tf.reduce_sum(x*(y-y_pred)) 
d_c = (-2/n) * tf.reduce_sum(y-y_pred)  
upm = tf.assign(m, m - learning_rate * d_m)
upc = tf.assign(c, c - learning_rate * d_c)

#starting session
sess = tf.Session()

#Training for epochs
for i in range(epochs):
    sess.run(y_pred)
    sess.run(d_m)
    sess.run(d_c)
    sess.run(upm)
    sess.run(upc)
    w = sess.run(m)
    b = sess.run(c)
    print(w,b)
```

Output for tensorflow :

```
0.7424335285442664 0.007335550424492317
1.1127687194584988 0.011031122807663662
1.2974962163433057 0.012911024540805463
1.3896400798226038 0.013885244876397126
1.4356019721347115 0.014407698787092268
```

The parameter **m has the same value** for both but **parameter c has different value** for both although the implementation is same for both.
The output contains first 5 values of parameter m and c. The output of parameter c using tensors is approximately half of the normal python.
I don't know where my mistake is.

For recreating the entire output:
[Repo containing data along with both implementations](https://github.com/aniketbote/learning-tensorflow/blob/master/Examples%20low%20level%20api/uni-variate_linear_regression_tensors.py)

The repo also contains image of graph obtained through tensorboard in events directory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that, in the TF implementation, the updates are not being performed atomically. In other words, the implementation of the algorithm is updating `m` and `c` in an interleaved manner (e.g. the new value of `m` is being used when updating `c`). To make the updates atomic, you should simultaneously run `upm` and `upc`:

```
sess.run([upm, upc])
```

Comment: This solved the problem but i did not understand how the value of m is getting used in upc?

Comment: `m` is being used to compute `Y_pred` and this alters the value of the loss (and therefore the gradient wrt. `c`)